# Code Synthax BBCode Inline Fix

Tags: javascript, css, bbcode

So I'm trying to make a custom BBCode for my forum that will properly color coding by it's language. It works great but it's appearing completely inline and doesn't line break at all like it should.
Here is the coding:

```html
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://z3.ifrm.com/63/1/0/p509771/prism.css" />

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function addLang(nClass, nName) {
    $('blockquote dt:contains(' + nClass + ')').parents('blockquote').find('code').addClass('language-' + nClass);
    $('blockquote dt:contains(' + nClass + ')').text('Code: ' + nName);
}

addLang('css', 'CSS');
addLang('javascript', 'JavaScript');
addLang('php', 'PHP');
addLang('sql', 'SQL');
addLang('c++', 'C++');
addLang('c#', 'C#');
addLang('python', 'Python');
addLang('java', 'Java');
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://z3.ifrm.com/63/1/0/p509772/prism.js"></script>
```

Here is how it appears: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwTsZ.png
Here is an example of how I want it to appear: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qvg0T.png

Comment: can you inspect element and check they are being wrapped in `<pre>` tags.

Comment: They are being wrapped in <span> tags.

Comment: Not sure if this is frowned upon but I kinda need this to be answered please. So Bump?